# É possível pegar um dado de um JSON usando uma variável pré-definida?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Eu possuo um link com um atributo que possui a informação de qual dado do JSON deve ser obtido.

```
<a href="#" data-json-code="code_118"></a>
```

E possuo o código responsável pelo comportamento do mesmo, que deve ser:

1. Pegar o atributo;
2. Buscar esse atributo no json;
3. Exibir as informações do json no console.

Eu fiz dessa forma, mas sempre retorna "undefined":

```
$('.c-productCard a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var jsonCodeProduct = $(this).attr('data-json-code');

    var jsonUrl = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/mc9ig';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        url: jsonUrl,
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            console.log('before send');
        },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result.jsonCodeProduct);
        },
        error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('erro');
        },
        complete: function() {
            console.log('complete');
        }
    });
});
```

Se por acaso eu retirar o `jsonCodeProduct` da chamada `success` o json inteiro é exibido no console (como esperado).

A pergunta é, como fazer para que o dado da variavel `jsonCodeProduct` seja o "*seletor*" para exibir o dado correspondente do `JSON`?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? apresente a estrutura do seu Json, para que eu possa elaborar melhor a minha resposa.

Comment: Consegui @LeandroAngelo, muito obrigado, a solução era justamente a que você indicou, bastava colocar o "jsonCodeProduct" entre colchetes após o result.

Comment: Então, por favor, marque a proposta como resposta da sua pergunta, isso vai ajudar outras pessoas que estiverem passando pelo mesmo problema a encontrar a solução mais rápido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como qualquer objeto no javascript, você pode obter o valor de uma propriedade através de seu nome, no seu caso seria:

```
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result[jsonCodeProduct]);
    }
```

Veja o exemplo abaixo, também se você está utilizando atributos `data` e `jquery` você pode recuperar a informação de uma forma um pouco mais elegante.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var jsonCodeProduct = $(this).data('json-code');

  console.clear();
  console.log(objExemplo[jsonCodeProduct]);


});

var objExemplo = {
  code_118: { nome : 'Produto 1' , preco : 'R$10,00'},
  code_119: { nome : 'Produto 2' , preco : 'R$20,00'}
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="exemplo" href="#" data-json-code="code_118">Produto 1</a>
<a id="exemplo" href="#" data-json-code="code_119">Produto 2</a>
```